# Does the HP Proliant DL360 come with multiple NIC's?

Tags: networking, hp, hp-proliant, nic

Would someone be able to clarify multiple NIC cards to me, we have recently invested in a HP Proliant DL360, although do the network adapter cards come with 4 NIC's?

E.g.:

> Networking: 2 HP NC382i Dual Port Multifunction Gigabit Server
>   Adapters—4 x 1 Gb NIC ports

How many separate networks could I create with the specification listed above?

Any help would be appreciated

- Information obtained from: http://h20195.www2.hp.com/V2/GetPDF.aspx/4AA0-6314ENW.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specs are a little misleading, but it's essentially trying to say that the server has TWO 2-port cards, giving a total of FOUR 1GB NICS. The question about how many separate networks is irrelevant as you can configure subinterfaces and VLANs. You can have FOUR physical connections using this server, though.

Answer (score 2):

This says it has 2 cards, each with 2 ports. That's why it says 4 x 1 Gb NIC ports.

So, it has 4 ports. With VLANs and IP aliasing, you can put as many "separate networks
 as you wanted on it - but you could do the same thing with a single port, so I'm still unsure why that's part of your question.

Comment: Can't a port simply mean an additional space on the existing NIC?, e.g. an NIC with additional ports to add to the physical network

Comment: That is what it means. You have two physical network cards, and each one has two ports.